# Keyframes not setting where I place them

Tags: keyframes

I have 3 layers. I have the 1st layer animated over 160 keyframes. I am not sure as to which of the other layers is doing it but as I set a frame at say frame 20, it shows up at frame 40 instead, but claims the values are at frame 20. [image: Example problem]

Also, when I drag the slider, if I drag it to frame 40, the frame count says I am on frame 40 but the slider jumps to frame 20. Is there a way to fix this as I have no idea what has caused it.

Here is the dope sheet if it helps
[image]
I thought it may be worth noting that I originally had the earth do 2 rotations from 0-160 and the clouds to only do 1 rotation but when rendered the playback is strange and only does one rotation despite being set up for 2.
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Have done. I plan to redo this once I have learned the features I want but also want to find out what happened in order to prevent this in future. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: yes that's weird, in other words you can't put the timeline greenline where you want. If you copy paste (ctrl C + ctrl V) your objects in a new file it will work correctly but it doesn't answer what's happening there.

Comment: Thanks for that even is it's a workaround to fix will still be workable. I can copy them over and continue practicing with the elements I want in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh ok I've found out, you need to go in the *Properties* panel > *Render* > *Dimensions* > *Time Remapping*, and choose 100 / 100

Comment: Thanks for that. Despite completing a diploma in gaming there is still much for me to learn. I love blender.stackexchange such a helpful community. I would love to know what time remapping is used for. Something exciting and new to learn about.